# Game Wont Start

Tags: c#, xna, directinput

I'm using DirectInput with XNA however for some strange reason my game will not start when I have the following code implemented:

```
DeviceList gameControllerList = Manager.GetDevices(DeviceClass.GameControl, EnumDevicesFlags.AttachedOnly);
```

That really breaks my game, commenting the line works though leaving it in breaks it. I have absolutely no idea why. I have `Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput` referenced and everything. I even started a whole new project and just entered that line but had no luck in the game starting up.

This is literally my complete code, I just call `Input.InitializeController()` from the initialize method in `Game1()`.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput;

namespace InputTesting{
    class Input{
        public void InitializeController(){
            DeviceList gameControllerList = Manager.GetDevices(DeviceClass.GameControl, EnumDevicesFlags.AttachedOnly);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what the deal is with this I am completely stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details? Does it crash? Throw an unhanded exception? What happens if you step passed that line in the debugger?

Comment: Sure I'll try. The game just simply wont start I have to hit the stop debugging button to shut it all down. Therefor it doesn't crash because nothing starts up. No errors are thrown what so ever. Something interesting to note might be this: I've changed the output type to a Console I'm sure your familiar with this. It makes it so that once I hit the debug button a Console and the game window both come up. With that line enter the console comes up but the actual game window doesn't.

Comment: would re-installing the DirectX SDK help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using XNA 4.0 then your problem is due to XNA not supporting DirectInput properly.

In order to get your device working with your program you'll need to either roll back to XNA 3.1 or use a wrapper that allows Direct Input in 4.0, I'd recommend going with the wrapper SlimDX.